# Facebook Share Data URI Image

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, html5-canvas, data-uri

I have an application where users can interactively design elements on a HTML5 canvas. I would like to share the canvas image via Facebook.

I was planning on creating a dynamic page and pass in a Data URI but Facebook does not accept a Data URI image and requires an absolute image path.

I really don't want to head down the path of storing the image on server, even temporarily, but I am afraid that this is my only option? Is there another avenue I should be researching?

Answer (score 2):

I found some nice code for that , looks fine . You can also see who it looks for twiter at ["How to post image (canvas) to the facebook , twiter"](http://gorigins.com/posting-a-canvas-image-to-facebook-and-twitter/)

```
// Canvas Object
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// load image from data url
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
};

imageObj.src = 'panda_dark.png';

function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return new Blob([ab], {type: 'image/png'});
}

$('#shareFB').click(function () {
    var data = $('#canvas')[0].toDataURL("image/png");
    try {
        blob = dataURItoBlob(data);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.status === "connected") {
            postImageToFacebook(response.authResponse.accessToken, "Canvas to Facebook/Twitter", "image/png", blob, window.location.href);
        } else if (response.status === "not_authorized") {
            FB.login(function (response) {
                postImageToFacebook(response.authResponse.accessToken, "Canvas to Facebook/Twitter", "image/png", blob, window.location.href);
            }, {scope: "publish_actions"});
        } else {
            FB.login(function (response) {
                postImageToFacebook(response.authResponse.accessToken, "Canvas to Facebook/Twitter", "image/png", blob, window.location.href);
            }, {scope: "publish_actions"});
        }
    });
});


function postImageToFacebook(token, filename, mimeType, imageData, message) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("access_token", token);
    fd.append("source", imageData);
    fd.append("no_story", true);

    // Upload image to facebook without story(post to feed)
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=" + token,
        type: "POST",
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("success: ", data);

            // Get image source url
            FB.api(
                "/" + data.id + "?fields=images",
                function (response) {
                    if (response && !response.error) {
                        //console.log(response.images[0].source);

                        // Create facebook post using image
                        FB.api(
                            "/me/feed",
                            "POST",
                            {
                                "message": "",
                                "picture": response.images[0].source,
                                "link": window.location.href,
                                "name": 'Look at the cute panda!',
                                "description": message,
                                "privacy": {
                                    value: 'SELF'
                                }
                            },
                            function (response) {
                                if (response && !response.error) {
                                    /* handle the result */
                                    console.log("Posted story to facebook");
                                    console.log(response);
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    }
                }
            );
        },
        error: function (shr, status, data) {
            console.log("error " + data + " Status " + shr.status);
        },
        complete: function (data) {
            //console.log('Post to facebook Complete');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Tanks for sharing this code! :) I will try it right now!

Comment: The publish_actions permission has been removed sice August 1st, 2018. :(